# Why does Shiina always say "how shallow-minded"?

Tags: angel-beats

She usually says the phrase "how shallow-minded" (あさはかなり,asahaka nari). Is the fact that [she came from the past (a.e Feudal Japan) and was born in Ancient Japan](http://angelbeats.wikia.com/wiki/Shiina#Background) has something to do with it?

[image]

Comment: The suffix [-なり](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A#.E5.8F.A4.E5.85.B8.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E8.AA.9E) is an ancient word.  The repeated usage of the phrase suggests that she is from the past.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the wiki page you linked to, it's most likely because she's from an earlier era.

Also, being a trained assassin, she most likely views the actions of other characters as childish and foolish, so she just gives her honest opinion on the matter.